# Localizing a currency range

Tags: string-formatting, currency, intl, react-intl, formatjs

A combination of formatjs & javascript's native `Intl.NumberFormat()` supports formatting of numbers as currency in various cultures and units.  But how can I format a *range* of currency as `$1,000.00 - 5000.00`.

Without repeating the symbol, where ever and however it is normally displayed?

Using `react-intl`:

```
<FormattedNumber value={minVal} style="currency" currency="USD" />
 - <FormattedNumber value={maxVal} style="currency" currency="USD" />
```

This will show `$1,000.00 - $5000.00` which does not match my design spec.  Stripping away the currency symbol off of the second value seems like a hackey strategy since I shouldn't/can't easily know the symbol to strip.

Formatting just as a regular decimal would be strictly incorrect - currency rules dictate different numbers of digits for the "minor units" depending on the currency.

And what about if the currency symbol is, I don't know, displayed at the end for the culture instead of at the beginning?  (Does that happen?)

Comment: Did you find a nice solution? I'm having the same problem here. Thanks

Comment: Nope ..........

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com)? The [locales documentation](http://numeraljs.com/#locales) seems like it could do what you're looking for. They have [a number of locales](https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js/tree/master/locales) already and are happy to welcome more as contributions.

**Update:** looks like someone [already created an Angular integration](https://github.com/baumandm/angular-numeraljs) too.